# HelloWorld console application fails to publish with ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

thanks in advance. Publishing with my VisualStudio/ClickOnce I get always the following error.

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\carlos\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\publish\ConsoleApplication1.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Configuration system failed to initialize
    + Unrecognized configuration section startup. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\dfsvc.exe.Config line 2)
```

The dfsvc.exe.Config is:

`<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="false">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku="client" />
    </startup>
</configuration>`

Is something that I should install on my PC? Thanks again.

Comment: Have you installed the 64 bit framework? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/97d4f63a-538a-4c4e-8091-72d56e7659a0

Comment: @PreetSangha Yes, I have it installed

Comment: And can you tell us what in the config file?

Comment: I fixed it... I don't know exactly which was the fix, I did three steps: repaired .net fx installation, ran mage.exe -cc and rebooted

Comment: Put those in an answer. and well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,
I don't know exactly which was the fix, I did three steps:

1 - I repaired .net fx intallation
2 - Ran mage -cc to clear clickonce store
3 - Rebooted

thanks